# Calling a switch case function from inside HTML

Tags: php, html, json

I am having problems trying to use a switch case to display an image if the `tank_id` matches the case string.

Here is my code:

```
...//
<?php foreach ($tank_stats['data']['1076056102'] as $key => $value) { ?>               
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo tank_IDs();?></td> //should display the correct tank image depending on what tank_id string in JSON

      <td><?php echo number_format($value['all']['battles']); ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($value['all']['wins']); ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($value['all']['losses']); ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($value['all']['frags']); ?> </td>  
    </tr>
<?php } ?> 
 ...//

<?php function tank_IDs () {
  switch ($tank_stats['tank_id']) {
      case "3649":
        echo '<img class="tanks" src="tank_1.png"/>';
        break;

      ...//

      default:
        echo '<img class="tanks" src="tank_2.png"/>';
 }
}
?>
```

What I want is to call my switch case function 'tank_IDs' inside the  in my table, and if the tank_id matches the tank JSON data, it displays the correct image.

So in my first case, if tank_id is "3649" it should display the correct tank pic. At the moment, it is displaying the 'default' case image in my case function.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `$tank_stats` doesn't exist in the `tank_IDs` function's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the ID available to the function.

You could also change the `echo`'s to `return`'s as you are using an echo in the `<td><?php echo tank_IDs($tank_stats['tank_id']); ?></td>` and it is always better to return data from a function rather than have the function generate output itself.

```
function tank_IDs ($tankId) {
  switch ($tankId) {
      case "3649":
        return '<img class="tanks" src="tank_1.png"/>';


  //...

      default:
       return '<img class="tanks" src="tank_2.png"/>';
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
<td><?php echo tank_IDs($tank_stats['tank_id']); ?></td>
```

Comment: Could also suggest changing the `echo`'s in the function to `return` or removing the `echo` from `<?php echo tank_IDs($tank_stats['tank_id']);`

Comment: You are right. I blindly copied his function lol. I updated my answer.

Comment: Worth putting a little note in your answer saying you have done that an why

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the tip! Despite the age of my account, I am still a little green on actually participating on SO.